# 'this' is returning undefined on a class member

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io

When I instantiate this class, upon calling the `init()` function, I'm getting an undefined. But inside `emit('updateRoomsRequest')` callback, I'm able to console log `this.roomsData` and see the values received through the socket connection.

```
export class LoginService {
    roomsData: string[];
constructor(private socket: Socket) {}

init(connect: string): string[]{
    this.socket.on(connect, () => {
        this.socket.emit('updateRoomsRequest', {}, (data: string[]) => {
            this.roomsData = data;
            console.log(this.roomsData); //this is logging data correctly
        });
    });

    return this.roomsData; //this is returning undefined
}
}
```

this is the instantiation :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    rooms: string[];
    constructor(private LoginPageService: LoginService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.rooms = this.LoginPageService.init('connect');
        console.log(this.rooms); //undefined as well
    }

    }
```

Comment: The problem here is that this.roomsData in your init function is being returned immediately. The socket still needs to listen to emit events then thats the only time the roomsData gets the actual content. This is an async problem. You can solve this with observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its about the order of execution. Line A executes before Line B:

```
this.socket.on(connect, () => {
    this.socket.emit('updateRoomsRequest', {}, (data: string[]) => {
        this.roomsData = data; // LINE B
    });
});

return this.roomsData; // LINE A
```

And therefore it is undefined at LINE A.

## FIX

Use callbacks, or promises or observables to chain your async code